# AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

So i was trying to add a method that will display data usage in the QS panel of my ROM from: https://github.com/Extended-UI/android_frameworks_base/commit/ca5707055fc7ba516ab93fd128291264b0332825

But the systemUI kept crashing. Here is the log:

```
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.systemui, PID: 2297
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PanelView.getExpandedFraction()' on a null object reference
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.StatusBar.updateBlurVisibility(StatusBar.java:1127)
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.StatusBar.updateIsKeyguard(StatusBar.java:3308)
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.StatusBar.access$1600(StatusBar.java:264)
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.StatusBar$15.onStartedWakingUp(StatusBar.java:4008)
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.systemui.keyguard.-$$Lambda$TPhVA13qrDBGFKbgQpRNBPBvAqI.accept(Unknown Source:2)
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.systemui.keyguard.Lifecycle.dispatch(Lifecycle.java:39)
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.systemui.keyguard.WakefulnessLifecycle.dispatchStartedWakingUp(WakefulnessLifecycle.java:68)
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.systemui.keyguard.KeyguardLifecyclesDispatcher$1.handleMessage(KeyguardLifecyclesDispatcher.java:67)
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7355)
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-16 20:04:37.311  2297  2297 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
```

The code that i used is here

```
public void updateBlurVisibility() {

    int QSBlurAlpha = Math.round(255.0f * mStaticNotificationPanel.getExpandedFraction());

    if (QSBlurAlpha > 0 && !dataupdated && !mIsKeyguard) {
        DataUsageView.updateUsage();
        dataupdated = true;
    }

    if (QSBlurAlpha > 0 && !blurperformed && !mIsKeyguard && isQSBlurEnabled()) {
        Bitmap bittemp = ImageUtilities.blurImage(mContext, ImageUtilities.screenshotSurface(mContext));
        Drawable blurbackground = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bittemp);
        blurperformed = true;
        mQSBlurView.setBackgroundDrawable(blurbackground);
    } else if (QSBlurAlpha == 0 || mState == StatusBarState.KEYGUARD) {
        blurperformed = false;
        dataupdated = false;
        mQSBlurView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    mQSBlurView.setAlpha(QSBlurAlpha);
    mQSBlurView.getBackground().setAlpha(QSBlurAlpha); 
}
```

What i can possibly do to correct it?

Comment: Your not getting value from this function `mStaticNotificationPanel.getExpandedFraction()`.

Comment: where did you initialize `mStaticNotificationPanel`?

Comment: protected static NotificationPanelView mStaticNotificationPanel;

I have it defined like this. 
Looks like i forgot to initialize with 
   mStaticNotificationPanel = mNotificationPanel;